# JQuery Form does not switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I was trying to create a form (step by step) with a progress bar over it. I have this code down here:

The problem i have is that the form shows up from the last `fieldset` and does not collect my information. What is wrong, how can i fix it?

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>


    <style class="csscreations">/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
    height: 100%;
    /*Image only BG fallback*/
    background: url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
    /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
    background: 
        linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
        url('http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/media/gs.png');
}

body {
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
    background: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 20px 30px;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 10%;

    /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
    position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
    width: 100px;
    background: #27AE60;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #2C3E50;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #666;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
    counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -50%;
    top: 9px;
    z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
    /*connector not needed before the first step*/
    content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
    background: #27AE60;
    color: white;
}




</style></head>
    <body>

    <!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
        <li class="active">Social Profiles</li>
        <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.8); display: none;">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
        <input name="pass" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        <input name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        <input name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" type="button">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset style="display: none; left: 0%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.8);">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
        <input name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" type="text">
        <input name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" type="text">
        <input name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" type="text">
        <input name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" type="button">
        <input name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" type="button">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset style="display: block; left: 0%; opacity: 1;">
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
        <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
        <input name="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
        <input name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text">
        <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone" type="text">
        <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
        <input name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" type="button">
        <input name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //de-activate current step on progressbar
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show(); 
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
            scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
            left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'left': left});
            previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
        }, 
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: The reason your form shows the last `fieldset` on load is that the first two have `display: none; opacity: 0;` in their style tags, whereas the last one has `display: block; opacity: 1`. You're explicitly setting the last fieldset as the visible one. What is your question?

Comment: _does not collect my information_....i don't understand it. Would you plz mention what is the motto of displaying last `fieldset` first.

Comment: i mean it doesnt submit.

Comment: @DavidHedlund That fixed my problem about displaying. But my progress bar still show the 3. page at the beginning.

Comment: here is the link of my code:  [PHP TEST SERVER](http://phptestserver.tk/test.php)

Comment: You're giving us a lot of code in an untidy manner, and enumerating several problems without very much context. In the future, when you have code samples, please provide a fiddle, along with the relevant pieces of code. [This is the format we want to see your code in](http://jsfiddle.net/HPtH9/). Second, let us know what you've tried.  As for your progress bars, they all have the `active` class in the markup. Why? Have you built this?

Comment: _All_ of your progressbar’s `LI` get the class `active` right from the start (and also keep it after each step) – so go fix your logic that _sets_ this class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**

> The problem i have is that the form shows up from the last fieldset

Your code specifies explicitly this:

```
<fieldset style="opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.8); display: none;">
...
<fieldset style="display: none; left: 0%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.8);">
...
<fieldset style="display: block; left: 0%; opacity: 1;">
```

**2.**

> But my progress bar still show the 3. page at the beginning

Again, this is what your markup specifies. All items are active:

```
<ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li class="active">Social Profiles</li>
    <li class="active">Personal Details</li>
</ul>
```

**3.**

> it doesnt submit

And what's your code for form submit?

```
$(".submit").click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

---

There are no clear questions to be answered here. Everything behaves exactly as your code instructs. There are no apparent bugs, at least not matching your problem description. Have you written this? Do you understand any of this code? If you want something to happen on submit, what have you tried to this end?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the progress bar class `active`, and fix the fieldset inline css `opacity` and `display`, and you forget to set `animating` to `false` when previous animate complete.

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/voduzuci/1/edit